# The textView containing messages count return to null when call back from anather activty

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm creating an app connected to firebase database. I want to show messages rececvied to user in menu so I use code in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`,

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.Messages);

        View actionView = menuItem.getActionView();
        smsCountTxt = (TextView) actionView.findViewById(R.id.notification_badge);


       // setupBadge();

        actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

My problem is that when i return back from anathor activity the textView `smsCounttxt` become null and i am having that error.

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

this is the position of error,

```
     if (pendingSMSCount == 0) {
                            if (smsCountTxt.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                                smsCountTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        } else {
                            smsCountTxt.setText(String.valueOf(Math.min(pendingSMSCount, 99)));
                            if (smsCountTxt.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                                smsCountTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Where is `smsCounttxt` defined? It might help if you post the code from all activity.

Answer (score 0):

@ali-dlala
Your variable smsCountTxt is null when you are setting the text on return. You have to call invalidateOptionsMenu() to recreate the context menu. This will call onPrepareContextMenu() where you will reinitialize the menu with correct values